# % operator to compute the remainder in CLISP

Tags: lisp, clisp

I am running a CLISP in mac os X terminal. A simple eval like (% 3 5) outputs
    EVAL: UNDEFINED FUNCTION %

It evaluates correctly in the ielm mode in emacs. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Common Lisp is not the same language as Emacs Lisp. When it comes to Common Lisp it has [very good documentation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/index.htm) so you should be able to find all [numeric functions](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_number.htm) easily.

Comment: @mbratch Isn't a macro seriously overkill? I was just thinking of something like `(setf (symbol-function '%) #'rem)` (there may be a better way to write the same thing; I'm a Schemer, not a CLer).

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young It's not just overkill;  it's inconvenient;  you couldn't do `(mapcar '% xs ys)` if it were a macro.  Setting the symbol function, as you suggest, would be one option.  Another would be `(defun % (number divisor) (rem number divisor))` and to add some declarations to aim for inlining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of the function is `rem`: `(rem 5 3)`